# Change Wordpress navigation order

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Change the Wordpress navigation order without the use of Menu's or page order.

I want the Home page to be the standard first page en Contact page to be the last. Is this possible without the use of Wordpress Menu's or page order?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with CSS or JS. How does your current page code looks like? Can you post the code or link to the page?

Comment: I solved it by building my own nav function using wp_list_pages.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Can you post the solution so that others could benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with wp_list_pages:

function build_navigation_menu() {

```
// Get contact page by title
$contact_page = get_page_by_title( 'Contact' );

// If exists get ID
if ($contact_page) {

    $contact_id = $contact_page->ID;
}


// Get home page by title
$home_page = get_page_by_title( 'Home' );

// If exists get ID and fetch home page link
if ($home_page) {

    $home_id = $home_page->ID;

    $args = array(
        'include'       => $home_id,
        'title_li'      => '',
        'depth'         => 2
    );

    $home_page = wp_list_pages( $args );
}

// Get all links except contact and home
$args = array(
    'exclude'       => $contact_id . ',' . $home_id,
    'title_li'      => '',
    'depth'         => 2,
    'walker' => new pdc_walker()    
);

$pages = wp_list_pages( $args );

// If contact page exists fetch link 
if ($contact_page) {

    // Add call me now link
    $call_now = '<li class="call-now"><a href="#">Call now</a></li>';

    $args = array(
        'include'       => $contact_id,
        'title_li'      => '',
        'depth'         => 2        
    );

    $contact_page = wp_list_pages( $args );
}

$navigation_pages = $home_page . $pages . $contact_page . $call_now;

return $navigation_pages;
```

}